# Pass Python data to Django Templates & Jquery

Tags: jquery, python, json, django

I've been having to do one or other quite often - I'll give just one example: I have a little box with overviews of certain data obtained in python, but which doesn't happen to have the entire dataset, on the other hand using `flot_data|length` on the dataset I am passing with `json.dumps` gives the length of the string. So I added another helper dict with len(flot_data) as a key value `{{ flot_extras.length }}`

These kinds of redundant things happen on more than one occasion - strangely enough something like `{{ flot_extras.min }}` which is a non-json Python dictionary works in Jquery, while passing the entire dictionary to a variable does not.

What's the optimal way to pass/render a dataset and additional information when some of which needs to be rendered in Jquery and some of it by the Django template renderer? 
The redundancy seems inelegant, but as long as it's only 10s or even 100s of value should I even be worrying about it?

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can easily pass data from Django to JavaScript:</s>

```
<script>

    var context = {
      var1: {{ var1 }},
      var2: {{ var2 }},
      dictVar: {{ dictVar }}
    };

</script>
```

And response context would look like:

```
{ 'var1': 'A', 'var2': 'B', 'dictVar': json.dumps(someDict) }
```

**UPDATE:**

I'd suggest you to render array as html elements with additional data attributes to provide complete data

```
{% for item in array %}
  <div data-paramA="{{ item.paramA }}" data-paramB="{{ item.paramB }}">{{ item.paramC }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then jQuery reads necessary information from html elements and creates a flot chart.

Data attribute value can be also a json.dumped-dict or list.

Comment: uh, single variables - not dictionaries or lists as far as I can figure.

Comment: Did you even read my question? Obviously I can json.dumps a dictionary or an array... But if I json.dumps an array for a flot chart as well as trying to render it for a table with {% for item in array %} it's not going to work.